# Unity Burst Compiler failed — could not load System.Diagnostics.Tracing

Tags: unity, android, burst

I am using Unity 2023.3.f1
When building an Android app I get the following. I have zero idea what this means.
I've tried searching elsewhere but found nothing to fix it.

```
Building Library\Bee\artifacts\Android\AsyncPluginsFromLinker failed with output:
UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException: Burst compiler (1.8.4) failed running

stdout:
Error: Failed to find entry-points:
System.Exception: Error while hashing assembly C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Variations\mono\Managed\UnityEngine.dll ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Buffers.DefaultArrayPool`1.Rent(Int32 minimumLength)
   at Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.Storage.StringCollection.AddString(String value)
   at Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.CacheBuilder.ILHasher.ProcessAssemblyReference(AssemblyReferenceHandle assemblyReferenceHandle, StringCollection strings)
   at Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.CacheBuilder.ILHasher.ProcessAssemblyReferences(StringCollection strings)
   at Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.CacheBuilder.ILHasher.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<HashImpl>b__3()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.CacheBuilder.ILHasher.HashImpl()
   at Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.CacheBuilder.ILHasher.HashAssembly(String filePath, TaskFactory taskFactory)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.CacheBuilder.ILHasher.HashAssembly(String filePath, TaskFactory taskFactory)
   at Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.CacheRuntime.HashCacheLoader.CreateHashingResult(AssemblyNameReference assemblyNameReference, AssemblyLoader assemblyLoader, DebugLogWriter debugLogWriter)
   at Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.CacheRuntime.HashCacheAssemblyStore.GetAssemblyState(String assemblyName, AssemblyLoader assemblyLoader)
   at Burst.Compiler.IL.Server.EntryPointMethodFinder.LoadAllAssemblyReferences(AssemblyDefinition asmDef, Dictionary`2 visited, Dictionary`2 jobProducers, HashCacheAssemblyStore assemblyStore, AssemblyLoader assemblyLoader)
   at Burst.Compiler.IL.Server.EntryPointMethodFinder.FindEntryPoints(String[] rootAssemblyNames, HashCacheAssemblyStore assemblyStore, AssemblyLoader assemblyLoader, NativeCompilerOptions options, ProfileDelegate profileCallback, Boolean includeRootAssemblyReferences, Boolean splitTargets)
   at Burst.Compiler.IL.Server.FindMethodsJob.Execute(CompilerServerJobExecutionContext context)
stderr:

  at Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BclRunner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) [0x00237] in .\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.8.4\Editor\BurstAotCompiler.cs:1706 
  at Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BclRunner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) [0x0004d] in .\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.8.4\Editor\BurstAotCompiler.cs:1583 
  at Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BclRunner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) [0x00001] in .\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.8.4\Editor\BurstAotCompiler.cs:1558 
  at Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler.OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLsImpl (Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BurstAOTSettings settings, UnityEditor.Compilation.Assembly[] playerAssemblies) [0x00a76] in .\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.8.4\Editor\BurstAotCompiler.cs:706 
  at Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAOTCompilerPostprocessor.DoGenerate (UnityEditor.Compilation.Assembly[] assemblies) [0x0001b] in .\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.8.4\Editor\BurstAotCompiler.cs:265 
  at Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAOTCompilerPostprocessor.GenerateNativePluginsForAssemblies (UnityEditor.Build.IGenerateNativePluginsForAssemblies+GenerateArgs args) [0x0008a] in .\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.8.4\Editor\BurstAotCompiler.cs:179 
  at UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.GenerateNativePluginsForAssemblies (PlayerBuildProgramLibrary.Data.GenerateNativePluginsForAssembliesArgs args) [0x00050] in <582c35e8f45345d395e99f8e72e3c16d>:0 
  at Bee.BeeDriver.BuildRequest+<>c__DisplayClass63_0`1[T].<RegisterRPCCallback>b__0 (System.Object o) [0x00000] in <cbc6cae0703746c08eee7f40dbc1e66c>:0 
  at Bee.BeeDriver.BeeDriver_RunBackend+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<ProcessRPCRequest>b__0 () [0x00021] in <cbc6cae0703746c08eee7f40dbc1e66c>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <6aa56e57ab504395b555cf3ed50fa53d>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in <6aa56e57ab504395b555cf3ed50fa53d>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Bee.BeeDriver.BeeDriver_RunBackend.ProcessRPCRequest (Bee.BinLog.RPCActionMessage msg, Bee.BeeDriver.BuildRequest+RPCCallback rpcCallback, IPCConnection ipcConnection, System.Threading.Tasks.Task writePipeConnectionTask, Bee.BeeDriver.InternalState state) [0x00111] in <cbc6cae0703746c08eee7f40dbc1e66c>:0 
,
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

I am also getting the error:

```
Library\Bee\artifacts\Android\AsyncPluginsFromLinker: Failed to find entry-points:
    UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

But am not sure if it is connected

Comment: And I assume that this is not a completely empty project but rather one that was in development for quite some time which you are now building for the first time ever, meaning there is no way to pinpoint any particular change that broke the build?

Comment: Yep. Just the first time I am building. Up to now I have been runinng it inside Unity.

Comment: I know that hindsight is 20/20. But problems like that are the reason why you should regularly test your game not just in the editor but also try to build it for all platform you are targeting. Problems that only occur if the game is exported can be a nightmare to track down. But the less you did since the last time you ran the built game successfully, the fewer things there are that could be responsible.

Comment: @Philipp I tested it now by creating a new Unity app, changed platform to Android and then built.
Got the same errors.

Comment: @Philipp Made a small fix to the second error message given. For some reason one line didn't show here.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but I'd uninstall and reinstall Unity, and try clearing your library folder or reimporting packages. These errors seem to be in engine components, suggesting that something got corrupted in your installation, and a fresh copy might be enough to resolve it.

Comment: @DMGregory Your shot in the dark worked. I removed all installations of Unity I had and then installed the latest version. Now works. Classic "turn it off and on again"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, as DMGregory suggested, I did a complete uninstall and reinstall of Unity.
Also, made sure to remove all previous versions in order to be 100% sure there was no residue.

I then reinstalled and it works perfectly.